# How to Set Particular Area/Region Selected MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, mkmapview

Hi everyone I am trying to set a particular area of `MapView` selected like in image

[image]

a part of map highlighted and other looks dimmed. I am using `MKMapView` in my project and I have successfully drawn line on map but I am unable to dim area outside my selected area.

What I do is, allow user to draw line on `ImageView` and get `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects from touch points

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func btnActionApply(sender: UIButton) {
    viewDraw.hidden = true
    mapView.scrollEnabled = true
    for touches in arrTouches {
        var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        for p in touches {
            let c = mapView.convertPoint(p, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
            coordinates.append(c)
        }
        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: touches.count)
        mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }

    viewDraw.image = nil
    viewDraw.hidden = true
    mapView.scrollEnabled = true

}
```

> ```
> override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
>     if let touch = touches.first {
>         startPoint = touch.locationInView(viewDraw)
>         lastPoint = touch.locationInView(viewDraw)
>         self.touches = [startPoint]
>     }
> }
> override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
>     if let touch = touches.first {
>         let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(viewDraw)
>         self.touches.append(touch.locationInView(mapView))
>         drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
>         lastPoint = currentPoint
>     }
>     self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
> }
> override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
>     drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: startPoint)
>     self.touches.append(startPoint)
>     arrTouches.append(self.touches)
> }
> ```

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewDraw.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    viewDraw.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewDraw.frame.size.width, height: viewDraw.frame.size.height))
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)
    // 4
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    // 5
    viewDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    viewDraw.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    return lineView

}`
```

Here is what I get from this code

[image]

Please if anyone can help me to get desired results

Comment: I am not perfect in MapKit. But i will suggest you, You can add an dark overlay over whole map. And after that you can set brightness/blur effect on selected area.

Comment: @ZuhairHussain did u get the solution for ur requirement... i am also looking for the solution...

Comment: @sudhanshu.swastik you I used below MKMapKit method and it worked fine  

let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &outerCoordinates, count: outerCoordinates.count, interiorPolygons: innerPolygons)
mapView.add(polygon)

Comment: @ZuhairHussain: Can u please add objective-c solution for above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fist of all get outer coordinates like

```
var outerCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

for i in -90...90 {
     outerCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(i), longitude: -180))
}
for i in -180...180 {
      outerCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: Double(i)))
}
for i in -90...90 {
       outerCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(i * -1), longitude: 180))
}
for i in -180...180 {
       outerCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: Double(i * -1)))
}
```

> Now inner Polygon

```
var innerPolygons = [MKPolygon]()
```

> Insert all your inner polygons in innerPolygons array i.e.

```
var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]() 

// TODO: add all coordinates for inner polygon

let poly = MKPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
innerPolygons.append(poly)
```

> After adding all inner polygons

```
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &outerCoordinates, count: outerCoordinates.count, interiorPolygons: innerPolygons)
mapView.add(polygon)
```

Comment: Can u please add objective-c solution for above.